# Weird button placement in iOS app

Tags: discussion, status-completed, design, ios-app, back-button

This may just be me, but the back/forward buttons (<kbd><</kbd><kbd>></kbd>) in the iOS in-app browser seem too close to the refresh button (<kbd>↻</kbd>) and a little small. Just a thought.

[image: iOS Stack Exchange's in-app browser]

Comment: Yeah! I've been wondering if maybe they just forgot to make a retina image for it? They're exactly half the size they should be. [Here I scaled them 200%](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jYoTd.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for pointing this out.

We now have much prettier (and more usable) back/forward buttons:

[image]

This will be available in version **0.1.62.**